# How to SELECT a field without the first n characters and the last m characters?

Tags: html, mysql

I have a SELECT statement that is trying to view data from a single table. The data is encapsulated by HTML tags (`<p>` and `</p>`). For instance, one field might say:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

How do I tell the SELECT statement to discount the first 3 characters and the last 4 characters?

Comment: how do you output the query result to your page? If that's PHP - how about `strip_tags` ?

Comment: Sorry, not PHP output. I'm just doing a regular query. The DATA, however, *is* coming from PHP. That part works everywhere else the field is used but not for this current query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(data, 4, LENGTH(data)-7)
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what OP's asked for and the answer is correct. But the whole approach is faulty as hell - what if there will be not a `<p>` tag, but a `<span>` or `<h4>`..

Comment: I noticed, but this will get his current task done and he will find out why the approach is wrong by himself sooner or later. I can't imagine any answer that could magically feed him the lacking experience, especially with this poorly described task.

Comment: since we don't know anything about the DB and there might not be any tags just the `<p>` one, the answer is technically correct and solves the issue... then I guess +1 :)

Comment: This worked as I wanted it. There are ONLY `<p>` and `</p>` tags, so I was safe in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

If all data has only one opening tag at the beginning, and one closing tag at the end, like in your example, you could use this:

```
select
  case when instr(data, '</')>instr(data, '>') then
    substring(data, instr(data, '>')+1,instr(data, '</')-instr(data, '>')-1)
  else
    data
  end as stripped_data
from
  your_table
```

notice that this will strip also unmatched tags like `<p>Lorem Ipsum</strong>`